# How to find encoding type in xml file and parse using SAX Parser in Java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I have to parse an input XML file using XML Parser in Java program. But I am not sure about its encoding. Sometimes the file has ANSI encoding and sometime UTF encoding.

I need to properly parse the XML to avoid MalformedByteSequenceException: Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence exception.

Could anyone please give a direction on proceed with this problem?

Comment: Normally, XML files are not allowed to be of uncertain encoding. Either they're in a UTF- encoding, in which case the parser can trivially figure out which it is, or they're not in a UTF- encoding, in which case the file is required in to explicitly state its encoding in the XML declaration at the beginning of the file. There are no practical solutions designed to solve the problem of not respecting these requirements (beside, the standard is to have everything as utf-8 and let encoding problems stop to exist as a result.)

Comment: The file does not have that configuration of giving information of encoding type. I believe the input file is generated using some shell script or exported from GUI which is not clear. It is not possible to demand as they are generated by people who are not programmers. Is there any solution to convert to common encoding irrespective of any encoding type?

Comment: None practical. That's kind of the point of an encoding: they define what is the correct way to read something, which means the others are incorrect. You could try to loop through known encodings and check if you can read your file without error with that encoding. If you can, decide that it was the right encoding. However, that may be a wrong assumption, as a computer cannot tell that café is right and cafµ is wrong. Short of making the programmer as smart as you need your human operators to be, there is no solution.